# not able to retrieve subterm image in page-taxonomy.tpl.php

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming, drupal-taxonomy

I want my taxonomy pages to be styled in a particular way. For this I have done the necessary in template.php. Now I have page-taxonomy.tpl.php ready and working. I am using taxonomy image module to upload images to taxonomy terms. I am retrieving the images of a corresponding term using taxonomy_image_get_url($term->tid);and displaying them. Now I want to retrieve the subterms of this term, which I have been able to do using _taxonomy_term_children($term->tid)

The problem is I am not able to retrieve its image.

```
            <?php if ( arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term' && is_numeric(arg(2)) ) {
              $term = taxonomy_get_term(arg(2));
              $image_url = taxonomy_image_get_url($term->tid);
              print $image_url;
             }?>
            <div id="taxonomy_term_image"><img src="/sites/default/files<?php print $image_url;?>" /></div>
            <div id="taxonomy_term_description"> <?php print $term->description;?>                <?php print $images_url;?></div>
                              <?php print $feed_icons; ?><br/>
              Sub Categories:  <?php $taxonomy_children = _taxonomy_term_children($term->tid);
            foreach ($taxonomy_children as $value) {  
                $tax_child = taxonomy_get_term($value);
                print $tax_child->name;
                print $tax_child->description; 
                $subterm_image = taxonomy_image_get_url($taxchild->tid);
                                    print $subterm_image;
                }?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the HTML code to render the image.  Need to put it in as you did the parent image:

```
<img src="/sites/default/files<?php print $subterm_image;?>" />
```